# Sonarqube incorrectly reports "Unexpected missing generic font family "Roboto" and "Poppins""

Tags: react-native, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, saas, scss-lint

[Screen shot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74bpn.png)

Sonar Qube is showing this bug "Unexpected missing generic font family" even though this
Roboto and "Poppins" generic font family is included in the font-family set. there any real bug in this SCSS code snippet.

```
 .instructorNameText{
    color: $blue;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';
Unexpected missing generic font family
 }
```